# Remove lines with card details only

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed, grep

Input file:

```
SNO|PRODUCT|SUMMARY              | ADDRESS|DATE|  
101|111111|This cutomer is good|Adress1|01/01/2012|
101|111111|This cutomer contact is 223 456 7777|Adress1|01/01/2012|
101|111111|This cutomer is details 4450 2214 2254 2133|Adress1|01/01/2012|
101|111111|This cutomer is phone number is 223 124 4411|Adress1|01/01/2012|
101|111111|This cutomer is card 1245-2355-4452-1214-152|Adress1|01/01/2012|
101|111111|This cutomer is credit number 1245 2355 4452 1214 152|Adress1|01/01/2012|
```

Expected output_file:

```
SNO|PRODUCT|SUMMARY              | ADDRESS|DATE|
101|111111|This cutomer is good|Adress1|01/01/2012|
101|111131|This cutomer contact is 223 456 7777|Adress1|01/01/2012|
101|111141|This cutomer is phone number is 223 124 4411|Adress1|01/01/2012|
```

Remove records with card details. This can be present anywhere in the summary column.

Conditions to check are:

1. Phone number is 10 digits hence it is not to be removed.
2. Continuous numbers more than 10 digits to be removed
3. Continuous numbers more than 10 digits with inbetween spaces or hyphen or other special characters needs to be removed.

I tried this logic:

First to group the numbers as

1. `sed 's/\([0-9]\) \([0-9]\)/\1\2/g' input_file` - remove spaces in numbers
2. `sed 's/\([0-9]\)-\([0-9]\)/\1\2/g' input_file` - remove hyphen between numbers

Result : Achieved result as

```
SNO|PRODUCT|SUMMARY              | ADDRESS|DATE|     
101|111111|This cutomer is good|Adress1|01/01/2012|
101|111111|This cutomer contact is 2234567777|Adress1|01/01/2012|
101|111111|This cutomer is details 445022142254 2133|Adress1|01/01/2012|
101|111111|This cutomer is phone number is 2231244411|Adress1|01/01/2012|
101|111111|This cutomer is card 1245235544521214152|Adress1|01/01/2012|
101|111111|This cutomer is credit number 1245235544521214152|Adress1|01/01/2012|
```

Now I need to remove lines with numbers greater than 9,99,99,99,999 so that only the lines with card numbers will get removed.

Unable to do this check of greater than in Summary column.

Any help on this please?

Comment: Start reading *carefully* the [documentation of GNU awk](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html). It is worth your time. Your question is currently off-topic, you don't show the code you have tried.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for questions about programming, but we will not do all the work for you. Please show us what you have tried, what you expected to happen and what actually happened.

Comment: @ByteHamster I can see from the revision history that this question started out as a bit of a mess but I think that the input, expected output and attempt have all been shown now. In fact, I'd say it's clearer than quite of a lot of questions I see on these tags!

Comment: @Basile I think that the question is in a lot better shape than it was when you made that comment (though I still agree that the OP should invest some time in learning awk).

Comment: Come up with a better same input/output set - one that includes cases with different "special characters", multiple number in one summary section, repeated "special characters" between digits, etc. You know - the stuff that you can imagine might occur in your real input but would be hard to handle with a tool. With your current input you'll get answers that work on that specific input set but not on your real data and it might be hard for you to figure out which answers those are.

Comment: @TomFenech - You are totally right. I just changed my downvote to an upvote :)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using awk rather than sed, as it makes it easier to split the process up into steps. Here's an awk script that produces your desired output:

```
# set field separator to |
BEGIN { FS = "|" }

{
    # save third field
    summary = $3
    # remove everything not a digit from the start
    sub(/^[^0-9]+/, "", summary)
    # remove hyphens and spaces from what is left
    gsub(/[- ]/, "", summary)
    # print the whole record unless the number is too long
    if (length(summary) <= 10) print;
}
```

Testing it out:

```
$ cat file
SNO|PRODUCT|SUMMARY              | ADDRESS|DATE|  
101|111111|This cutomer is good|Adress1|01/01/2012|
101|111111|This cutomer contact is 223 456 7777|Adress1|01/01/2012|
101|111111|This cutomer is details 4450 2214 2254 2133|Adress1|01/01/2012|
101|111111|This cutomer is phone number is 223 124 4411|Adress1|01/01/2012|
101|111111|This cutomer is card 1245-2355-4452-1214-152|Adress1|01/01/2012|
101|111111|This cutomer is credit number 1245 2355 4452 1214 152|Adress1|01/01/2012|
$ awk -f script.awk file
SNO|PRODUCT|SUMMARY              | ADDRESS|DATE|  
101|111111|This cutomer is good|Adress1|01/01/2012|
101|111111|This cutomer contact is 223 456 7777|Adress1|01/01/2012|
101|111111|This cutomer is phone number is 223 124 4411|Adress1|01/01/2012|
```

By the way, it's *customer*, not cutomer :)

Comment: That would fail if other numbers appear in the summary. For example, try it if the summary field of the 2nd non-header input line started with `This 2nd cutomer contact ...` instead of just `This cutomer contact ...`. It also doesn't account for whatever other "special characters" the OP meant besides `-`.

Comment: Sure, I just made it work for the input shown in the example.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately the example's generally not very thorough and doesn't even cover the cases mentioned in the question text.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="|" }
{
    maxLgth = 0
    tail = $0
    while ( match(tail,/[0-9]([0-9]|[^[:alpha:]])+[0-9]/) ) {
        cur = substr(tail,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        gsub(/[^0-9]/,"",cur)
        curLgth = length(cur)
        maxLgth = (curLgth > maxLgth ? curLgth : maxLgth)
        tail = substr(tail,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
}
maxLgth > 10

$ awk -f tst.awk file
101|111111|This cutomer is details 4450 2214 2254 2133|Adress1|01/01/2012|
101|111111|This cutomer is card 1245-2355-4452-1214-152|Adress1|01/01/2012|
101|111111|This cutomer is credit number 1245 2355 4452 1214 152|Adress1|01/01/2012|
```

It's not clear what you mean by "special characters" so I assumed above you meant non-alphabetic characters.